# Correct way to update a record while calling an instance method.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, controller, put

When I call update I don't want to *just* much update the record as I want to:

1. Call a model function to update a property of the model.
2. Update the model.

--

```
def update
    @simulation = Simulation.find(params[:id])
    @simulation.next # This is a function that has some logic to changes a property of the simulation record
    @simulation.update(simulation_params) 
end
```

Is this the correct way of going about this, or should I be using a separate controller function or another route?

Comment: Was.MMMMMMMMMMDelicious taken?

Comment: No I just have a funny accent.

Comment: Is your next method just adding some attributes to @simulation so that your update method can save them along with your params?

Comment: It is changing an existing column variable on the model, then I want to save it after. The params never get changed only another value altered by next. So should I next/update or should I have a seperate method that does next/save.

Comment: Why not just a method named `next!` that does everything (including saving).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for clarity, I personally would create an instance method in `Simulation`, high level code should be something like..

```
#Simulation model
class Simulation 

  ....

  def next_and_update(attrs)
    next
    update(attrs)
  end

end

#controller
def update
  @simulation = Simulation.find(params[:id])
  @simulation.next_and_update(simulation_params)
end
```

Idea is, its ok to have 1-2 lines more, if you can read the code and understand whats happening.

Comment: I'm going this route, I like keeping as much logic as possible out of the controller and making them more readable.

Comment: @NNNNNNNNNNDelicious, glad to help, if you want to be more fancy, checkout rails `service objects` https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like "next" is a method that takes care of some behind-the-scenes nitty gritty before an update (or save). That being the case, what you're doing is reasonable. Another controller method or route wouldn't be necessary. If you want to stick with "update" you can.

In this case it won't make a difference whether you finish with update or with save. Update and save both update the record in the database.

Does that help?